# Swiper go to next matching line instead of next match?

Tags: isearch, ivy, visual-line-mode, swiper

When I use swiper to search and I press the down arrow key, it always goes to the next match even if that match is on the same line. Is there an easy way to go to the next line that has a match instead? Sometimes going to the next match is useful, but oftentimes I am looking for a particular use of a variable name, and I end up taking longer to go through variable declarations because they often contain the search term twice like `ObjectType object_instance;`.

Possibly relevant: I am using visual line mode.

Comment: Pressing `<down>` during `swiper` completion is meant to go to the next line. What you're describing (`<down>` goes to next match even on same line) sounds like what `swiper-isearch` does. Are you sure you're calling `swiper`?

Comment: @Basil indeed I'm using swiper-isearch. I don't remember if that's deliberate...

Comment: @Basil maybe b/c I need incremental for performance? swiper seems slower

Comment: I'm not sure whether `swiper-isearch` supports line-based navigation. Perhaps it's worth asking on the project's issue tracker, if there isn't already an issue for this: https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues

Comment: @Basil thanks, created https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues/2611